# Syntax error on token "in", Identifier expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNRYF.jpg)

I am getting a syntax error in javascript file out of nowhere all of a sudden
Eclipse Mars IDE
Error : 
Syntax error on token "in", Identifier expected

Code:

```
function getData (node) {
    var attrs = node.attributes || []
      , data = {};

    if (!attrs.length) return data;

    $.each(attrs, function (i, attr) {
      if (/^data-in-*/.test(attr.nodeName)) {
        data.in = data.in || {};
        data.in[attr.nodeName.replace(/data-in-/, '')] = attr.nodeValue;
      } else if (/^data-out-*/.test(attr.nodeName)) {
        data.out = data.out || {};
        data.out[attr.nodeName.replace(/data-out-/, '')] = attr.nodeValue;
      } else if (/^data-*/.test(attr.nodeName)) {
        data[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
      }
    })

    return data;
  }
```

Comment: in is a keyword in javascript, you cant use it as an attribute so `data.in = data.in || {};` is invalid

Comment: I don't think it's an actual error, the code is valid. The linter in your IDE seems to be overly sensitive. Is there an error when you run it in the browser as well?

Comment: @nathan.meadows since ES5 this is not the case anymore [MDN: Reserved word usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_word_usage). Some older browsers or editors will complain about it as syntax error.

Comment: @Prinzhorn it might be a problem (e.g. older IE browsers have a problem with Promise and `.catch( ... )` ), even if it is valid syntax since ES5.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you eclipse editor validating javascript statements for java.as long as it works in brower you dont have to worry about editor errors.